# Merge Word document data into CSV

Tags: vba, csv, ms-word

I currently have a CSV file that will have multiple different pieces of info, but it will have a document name always as the first column.  I have code that opens the CSV, then reads it into an array, but when it opens the document for merging it will open the document and merge all the rows making a total of currently 4 documents inside 1.

What I want is 1 document for each line, then close the merged document and open the next for merging then close and so forth for each line.  Each line could have different document names.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```vb
Dim LLCODE$, FileNo$, Defendant$
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = fs.OpenTextFile(UserDir$ + "combined12.csv")
objTextFile.skipline
Do Until objTextFile.AtEndofLine
    arrStr = Split(objTextFile.Readline, ",")
    LLCODE$ = arrStr(0)
    FileNo$ = arrStr(26)
    Defendant$ = arrStr(33)

    testdoc = FormDir$ + LLCODE$ + ".docx"

    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    With oWord
        .WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
        Set oDoc = Documents.Open(testdoc, ConfirmConversions:=True, ReadOnly:=False, Visible:=True)

        With oDoc.MailMerge
            .OpenDataSource Name:=UserDir$ + "combined12.csv", ConfirmConversions:=True, LinkToSource:=True
            .Execute 'Pause:=something
        End With

        ActiveDocument.SaveAs (UserDir$ + "Merge\" + FileNo$ + "-" + Defendant$ + ".docx")
        ActiveDocument.Close

        .WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
        'MsgBox ActiveDocument.Name
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
        Set oDoc = Nothing
    End With
    Set oWord = Nothing
```

Comment: Try using [this Microsoft Word note](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/216201/wd-how-to-programmatically-save-each-page-or-section-of-document-as-se) as a startpoint.

Comment: The code you posted is VBA not VBScript. If you ran it as VBScript you'd be getting "expected end of statement" errors. If you're running it as VBA: why are you creating new Word instances over and over? Without cleanup no less (setting `oWord = Nothing` doesn't terminate the instance). What do you need `MailMerge` for? Please take a step back and describe in more detail what your code is supposed to do (sample input and output would help). Also make your code a [mcve]. [Edit] your question to provide additional information.